# Orthogonal complement for a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S= \{x_1+x_5\}$ is a vector space in $R^5$.

Then what is the orthogonal complement for $S$?

*My interpretation:*

We can represent as $[1, 0, 0, 0, 1] [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]^{T} = 0$

So, the solutions for plane lies in null space and hence $S^{\bot}$ is the row space i.e., $c[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]$ for all real $c$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Are $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ a basis of $\mathbb R^5$? And $\{x_1+x_5\}$ is the span of the single vector $x_1+x_5$?

Comment: What does $S= \{x_1+x_5\}$ mean? So far two people here have two different guesses what $S$ you're talking about. The problem didn't say "$S= \{x_1+x_5\}$" - what does the problem really say?

Comment: You can check your own answer for reasonableness: the sum of the dimensions of the two subspaces should equal the dimension of the ambient space. Does it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See problem 1 http://home.iitk.ac.in/~arlal/MTH102/LA_Assignments/PS5_Soln.pdf

Comment: @amd but can't able to figure out which one is solution space and which one is an orthogonal complement subspace...

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \in \mathbb R^5: x_1+x_5=0\}.$

If so, you are correct,

$$S^{\perp}=\{c(1,0,0,0,1). c \in \mathbb R\}.$$

Comment: Please see the first question of http://home.iitk.ac.in/~arlal/MTH102/LA_Assignments/PS5_Soln.pdf once,,,, where did i go wrong?

Comment: @hanugm In the link it is $\mathbb R^4,$ not $\mathbb R^5,$ and $\{e_1+e_4,−e_1+ 3e_2−e_3\},$ not $\{x_1+x_5\}$. Did you link to the correct problem set?

Comment: @DavidK problem is different,  but the methods they are following is wrong it seems... I'm confused about whether I miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1$ and $x_5$ are respectively the first and last vectors in a basis of $\mathbb R^5$, and if $[1,0,0,0,1]$ is a row vector written in that basis,
then $[1,0,0,0,1] = x_1 + x_5,$ and
$$ \{c[1,0,0,0,1] : c\in\mathbb R\} = \{x_1 + x_5\}. $$

That is, $c[1,0,0,0,1]$ is $S$, not $S^\perp$.

It is perfectly OK to solve for $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]$ in the equation
$$[1, 0, 0, 0, 1] [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]^{T} = 0.$$
That solution set will give you $S^\perp.$
But the solution set is *not* $c[1,0,0,0,1]$ for all real $c$.
If $c$ is real and $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5] = c[1,0,0,0,1]$ then
$$[1, 0, 0, 0, 1] [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]^T
 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1](c[1, 0, 0, 0, 1])^T = 2c $$
and this is zero only when $c=0.$

The method in the problem set you linked to (in a comment) is correct but you must finish it correctly.